# Mvc3 razor posting multiple models to single controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a single model comprised of multiple models.

how do I post the collected values to a single action result in a single controller so I can call a stored procedure?

its pretty straight forward when I have a single model, but using multiple models, eludes me at the moment.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is done easily with a form post or get so long as you use html helpers (you dont have to use the helpers but its easiest to use in my opinion that way you dont have to worry about proper naming) within the form and the view is strongly typed to the model that contains the other models. This is the idea behind view models and form models http://web-matters.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-mvc-viewmodel-and-formmodel.html

Here is what you can do in razor:

```
html.textboxfor(x => x.class1.property)
```

Then in your post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(PageModel model)
model.class1.property (this will be the value of what was set in the form)
```

You can call your stored procedure from within the action.

Hope that was what you were asking.